# parallel running of Examples in feature file of a Cucumber-Gherkins Integration test

Tags: gherkin, cucumber-java

As a part of my gherkins test case. There are many examples in my feature file which run for all the scenarios in the gherkins test. 
I need to run these examples in parallel.

Has anyone else done something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using [qaf-gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) where it uses TestNG instead of cucumber. so you can run you scenarios in parallel by setting `parallel=methods` in testng configuration file. It will also allow you to run each iteration in scenario outline in parallel.